# Design Patterns: Reduce duplicate code from 2 methods that is almost the same in java

Tags: java, design-patterns, factory-pattern, delegation

I have several classes of vehicles such as truck, sedan, van, motorcycle. The common thing between them is that they all move, so I delegate it to a move class which contains these methods:

```
getSpeed()
setSpeed()
getDestination()
setDestination()
..
..
..
move()
```

Some vehicles move differently then others so I make a factory design pattern for it. So if it is it a car(truck,sedan, van) it would delegate to the MoveCarImpl class or if it is a motorcycle, it would delegate to the MoveBikeImpl class. My issue is. the bike and car has almost exactly the same move() algorithm. The only difference is that the bike algorithm calls 1 additional method at the end of move() method while car's move() algorithm doesn't. So now I have a lot of duplication of code in the MoveCarImpl class and MoveBikeImpl class. Any ideas on how to deal with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extend your car move implementation class with the bike move implementation class and override the move method.

Comment: @Dan Please don't forget to mark the answer accepted which helped most in solving the problem. See also [How does accepting an answer work](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)?

Answer (score 2):

Move the common code between `MoveCarImpl` and `MoveBikeImpl` in a base class `MoveImpl`. Inherit both the Move car and Move bike from it and for each method call the base class method  and then do some additional specific method call.

Answer (score 0):

You can have an util class and have a method in it with the common code used by both car and bike, but in the moveBikeImpl call that extra method after this util class's method.

Answer (score 0):

u can make a Move class, and write ur move method in this class.
extend two classes CarMove and Bike move from move class
CarMove will inherit the method, no need to do anything, BikeMove class can override method of move(), overrided method can call super move method and then endMove method(), since endMove() needs to be called at the end.

and u will have the flexibility to add another Move classes for truck, sedan e.t.c, that can inherit from Move class.

Answer (score 0):

Much as I respect your decision to use delegation over inheritance, I find that having two class hierarchies that parallel each other is a code smell.  If you find that adding a new type of vehicle to the system requires that you add two (or more) classes to independent inheritance hierarchies, then it may be time to reconsider the decision to delegate rather than inherit.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is for the Move class to contain a pointer back to the Vehicle class.  (You'd pass it into the constructor, and hold it as a member variable.  You would probably find Generics useful.)  The Move class can call back to the Vehicle class for some vehicle-specific behavior -- treating the Vehicle class as a kind of Strategy pattern.